# Gmail Filter Not Forwarding Email

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a Gmail filter set up to forward some emails to another account.

[image: Filters]

The filter is correctly finding all of the incoming emails and is labeling them "WAVE" as it is supposed to. But it is not forwarding the email as it says it will.

I have already entered the forwarding confirmation code that was sent to the receiving email. I have also followed each of the steps on several tutorials, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Just give a try to this-> change the order of the filters - first forward, then label.  Take a look [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/jCukq7_LIKo), someone has already faced similar problem.

Comment: I have tried it both ways and with no label at all...no good.  Thanks for the forum though, I was looking for that.

Comment: Is the other email set as an alias of your current email account?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Any update? I'm seeing mails get forwarded, but only after several hours sometimes.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120062/gmail-filters-delayed-substantially-in-forwarding-emails

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and in my case it turns out that I had expected to be able to list off multiple emails with commas as delimiters in the `From` field when setting up a filter. It turns out I have to use OR as a delimiter. Now forwarding is working for me.

Expected to work:

```
From: foo@email.com, bar@email.com
```

Actually works:

```
From foo@email.com OR bar@email.com
```

The autocompletion in the filters works with commas, but not `OR`, which makes it confusing UX. Here's a list of all the operators: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

Comment: This is the answer to my issue, I can't believe commas don't work!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an old question now but I just ran into the same issue and for me the solution was to *not* attempt to forward to an alias. I had to set the forward using the actual email address.

e.g. you have two emails:

- me@example.com (*actual email address*)
- support@au.example.com (*alias for above "me@example.com"*)

If you attempt to forward your gmail using the address *support@au.example.com* it **will not work**. You **must** forward to a non-alias address.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable "Allow less secure apps"

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en