# Gmail filters delayed substantially in forwarding emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I've set up a filter in Gmail that I need to forward certain emails to SMS. I need it to forward the emails immediately. They take from one to twelve hours to forward. I don't see any settings to set the timing for forwarding emails, nor do I see a point for that.

How can I get my Gmail emails to forward immediately?

Comment: what protocol do you use?

Comment: Sure it's not the recipient system? Do note that there are no guarantees for email delivery; certainly not based on time.

Comment: I'm sending via T-Mobile's email to sms address, as in 5551234567@tmomail.net. If I send an email to that address, I get it right away.

Comment: I send an email to gmail based on my camera detecting someone is at the door, once gmail receives the email it takes about 10 to 20 seconds to AUTOFORWARD the EMAIL to my phone which for most situations is okay, but for my use it is too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the first time I set this up, the filter didn’t take somehow. The second time, a message sent in the morning was sent in the evening, but after that, they have been forwarding as timely as expected.

Make sure your filter takes after you create it, and wait 24 hours for everything to resolve and propagate.